# How do you make values of radio buttons call variables?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I want to make the value from the selected radio button link to a variable inside the javascript. For example, if the button with value ‘intermediate’ is selected, it’ll put the variable intermediate_chords in place of text_chords.

I’ve managed to get this working to a point that when I put console.log(text_chords); it’ll show the correct variable name required, yet it’s in string format, completely different to the actual variable I want to use. Exact same goes for console.log(chord_images);. It shows the correct output but in string form.

I've also tried setting both text_chords & chord_images as null but when I did the output was *undefined*.

**Javascript Code**

```
let text_chords = beginner_chords;
let chord_images = beginner_images;

function newChord() {
    // Getting Radio Button Options
    var ele = document.getElementsByName('difficulty');
    // Working out which button is selected          
    for(i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
        if(ele[i].checked) {
            // Changing the state of t_c && c_i from beginner to whatever is selected
            let text_chords = (ele[i].value+"_chords");
            let chord_images = (ele[i].value+"_images");
            // t_c && c_i are now strings; need to be converted into variable of the same name
            console.log(text_chords);
            console.log(chord_images);
        }
    }
```

**HTML Code - For the radio buttons**

```
        <div class="difficulty_btn"><br>
            <form>
                
                <input type="radio" id="beginner_btn" name="difficulty" value="beginner" checked>
                <label for="beginner_btn">Beginner</label>

                <input type="radio" id="intermediate_btn" name="difficulty" value="intermediate">
                <label for="intermediate_btn">Intermediate</label>

                <input type="radio" id="advanced_btn" name="difficulty" value="advanced">
                <label for="advanced_btn">Advanced</label>
                  
                <input type="radio" id="mixed_btn" name="difficulty" value="all">
                <label for="mixed_btn">Mixed</label>
                
            </form><br>
        </div>
```

Please say if any of this needs further explanation, or if any further code should be provided.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way. Instead of creating variables based on user input, use [datasets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) to carry the information you want from radio to div tags. Here I have set up an event listener (one for the document to load first, then another to assign a click event to the radio buttons). So that it can be reusable with that default value, I made the 'showChordsFor' function separate.

```js
//let text_chords = beginner_chords;
//let chord_images = beginner_images;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('[name=difficulty]').forEach(radio =>
    radio.addEventListener('click', e => {
      let diff = e.target.value;
      showChordsFor(diff)
    }))

  let defDiff = document.querySelector('[name=difficulty]:checked');
  if (defDiff) showChordsFor(defDiff.value)
})

const showChordsFor = (diff) => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.chord').forEach(el => {
    if (el.dataset.level === diff || diff === 'all') el.classList.add('show');
    else el.classList.remove('show');
  })
}
```

```css
.chord {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="difficulty_btn"><br>
  <form>
    <input type="radio" id="beginner_btn" name="difficulty" value="beginner" checked>
    <label for="beginner_btn">Beginner</label>

    <input type="radio" id="intermediate_btn" name="difficulty" value="intermediate">
    <label for="intermediate_btn">Intermediate</label>

    <input type="radio" id="advanced_btn" name="difficulty" value="advanced">
    <label for="advanced_btn">Advanced</label>

    <input type="radio" id="mixed_btn" name="difficulty" value="all">
    <label for="mixed_btn">Mixed</label>

  </form><br>
</div>

<div class='chords'>
  <div class='chord' data-level='beginner'>Beginner Chord</div>
  <div class='chord' data-level='intermediate'>Intermediate Chord</div>
  <div class='chord' data-level='advanced'>Advanced Chord</div>
</div>
```